# How to Multiply Every Value in a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

So, currently I have this dictionary:

```
var data : [Int:Float] = [0:0,1:1,2:1.414,3:2.732,4:2,5:5.236,6:3.469,7:2.693,8:5.828,9:3.201]
```

I want to create a new dictionary, say "newData." I want "newData" to have the same keys as "data," but I want to multiply every value in "data" by some constant (say "multiple") to get the values in "newData." How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be fun to run some performance tests on the various solutions. So we all learn something.

Comment: `data.forEach { data[$0.0] = $0.1 * multiple }`, just a short mutable version if you don't need to keep the old dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newData = data

for (key, value) in newData
{
    newData[key] = value * multiple
}
```

Comment: why are you copying data to newData and iterating again just to change the value.
Plus remove value! force unwrap to only value,no need to force unwrap

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
let data : [Int:Float] = [0:0,1:1,2:1.414,3:2.732,4:2,5:5.236,6:3.469,7:2.693,8:5.828,9:3.201]
let factor: Float = 2
```

You can use the `reduce` method

```
let multiplied = data.reduce([Int:Float]()) { (var result, elm) -> [Int:Float] in
    result[elm.0] = elm.1 * factor
    return result
}
```

The result.

```
[3: 5.464, 2: 2.828, 4: 4.0, 9: 6.402, 5: 10.472, 6: 6.938, 7: 5.386, 0: 0.0, 8: 11.656, 1: 2.0]
```

> Please ignore the order since Dictionaries do not have one.

### Why this solution is better then a for loop?

The code I am suggesting here does follow the Functional Programming paradigm. There are several advantages over the classic for loop:

1. It's thread safe: since only immutable values are used, you don't have to worry about other threads that could change these values while you are using them.
2. <s>It's faster: under the hood the elements of the results are processed in parallel</s>
3. It's less error prone because it's more declarative: we are describing how the result should be, not how to build it.

Comment: I was looking for reduce method,thumbs up (Y) for that reduce

Comment: Incorrect, there is no parallelization involved. It is most definitely not faster than a `for` loop. The only real benefit I see to this approach is the thread-safety.

Comment: @VatsalManot: why do to say that there is no parallelization? Please give me a chance to answer to your comment before down voting it my solution ;)

Comment: @appzYourLife: Think about it for a second, what exactly could be "parallelized" here? `reduce` takes an initial element and a combiner function. Each element is combined with the previous combination. It is clearly a sequential process.

Comment: @VatsalManot: yes but the result is a `Dictionary` which has distinct slots (one for every `key`). Each slot can be calculated independently by the others. It's pretty similar to shaders in OpenGL. Many parallel operations that at the same time build the same final frame ;)

Comment: @appzYourLife: You are copying the initial dictionary over and over again, each time adding a new element. It _is_ a sequential process and still slower than the `for` loop solution.

Comment: @appzYourLife: You say "parallel calculation of the closures", but how can there be parallelized calculation of closures when the closures are called sequentially?

Comment: @VatsalManot: Nothing here does prevent a parallel calculation of the closures and finally a synchronized merge of them.

Comment: @appzYourLife: Except the fact that **there's no such thing** as a "parallel calculation of the closures and finally a synchronized merge of them". Here's [the actual implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3f635d04c75eaafe0c410854049ec52bed25a8ce/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L341) of `reduce`.

Comment: @appzYourLife: It is a sequential process, which uses a `for` loop internally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102810/discussion-between-vatsal-manot-and-appzyourlife).

Comment: I've retracted my downvote, thank you for recognizing the mistake in your otherwise accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on `map`

```
let dict1 = ["a":1, "b":2, "c":3]
// Make a copy since we don't want to modify the original
var dict2 = dict1
let multiple = 5

dict2.map { (k,v) in dict2[k] = v*multiple }
```

I did some simple performance testing with a 10000 and 100000 element array the various solutions proposed perform like this

1. For Loop:  10000 elements 1.28 ms, 100000 elements 12.28 ms
2. Map(): 10000 elements 1.24 ms, 100000 elements 12.23 ms
3. Reduce(): 10000 elements 2.36 ms, 100000 elements 17.18 ms

But you don't have a 10000+ element array. It's just worth noting the difference.

Comment: Why on earth would you use `map` over `forEach`, or even a `for` loop? You just end up wasting resources, in the form of a useless `Array<Void>`.

Comment: Yeah, the return value is ignored which does take up memory for a brief time, but it is interesting that it is faster than the for loop. `forEach` would have been a better choice. And it performs the same as `map` without the extra array creation

Comment: It's not faster than a `for` loop. `map` internally uses a `for` loop, and therefore cannot be faster than one.

Comment: Oh I see. I used the for loop that is downvoted, It doesn't copy the array first so it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 4, `Dictionary` has a property called [`mapValues(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995348-mapvalues). `mapValues(_:)` has the following declaration:

> Returns a new dictionary containing the keys of this dictionary with the values transformed by the given closure.

```
func mapValues<T>(_ transform: (Value) throws -> T) rethrows -> Dictionary<Key, T>
```

---

The Swift 5 Playground sample code below shows how to use `mapValues(_:)` in order to create a new dictionary by multiplying every value of an existing dictionary:

```
let multiple: Float = 2
let data: [Int : Float] = [0 : 0, 1 : 1, 2 : 1.4, 3 : 2.7, 4 : 2, 5 : 5.2]

let newData = data.mapValues { (value: Float) -> Float in
    return value * multiple
}
//let newData = data.mapValues { $0 * multiple } // also works

print(newData) // [3: 5.4, 4: 4.0, 2: 2.8, 0: 0.0, 1: 2.0, 5: 10.4]
```